# Herokuにデプロイ出来ません【Node.js+Express】

Tags: git, node.js, ubuntu, heroku

Node.jsとExpressでサイト構築をしています。

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "Heroku"
$ heroku login
~~~~メールとパスワードを入力~~~~
$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
$ git push heroku master
```

上記の手順でUbuntuからHerokuへデプロイしようとしているのですが
以下のようなメッセージ＆エラーが出ます。

```
Counting objects: 12961, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (11964/11964), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 425298626 bytes)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

どうもファイル数が多すぎるのが問題なのかな？と思うのですが
実際こんなに多くのファイル数を`git add .`したつもりがありません。
もしかすると、node_modules以下のファイルが入ってしまっているのが原因かもしれないと思い
以下のようにremoveをして、コミットをしてみても上手く行きませんでした。

```
git rm --cached -r node_modules/
git commit -m "remove"
```

私自身は、GitもNode.jsもHerokuも超初心者なので、何でも良いので
原因に当たりそうなものがあれば教えてほしいです。

Answer (score 1):

gitの設定で`http.postBuffer`の値を十分大きなものに変更してからpushしてみてください。

`$ git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`

参考：
- [Git Push Fails - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html)
- [git push すると fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly が出る - MasKのpermission denied.](http://mask.hatenadiary.com/entry/2014/06/04/151419)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみましたが、同じ内容のエラーが出ました。別の解決法が必要なようです。

Answer (score 0):

Herokuの無料プランでは容量が100MBまでしか利用できないらしく、使用できるメモリにも制限があるようなので、もしかするとそれが原因かもしれません。ただ、有料プランに契約する方法が難しく、手こずっているため検証できていません。